# Autofac to NetCoreApp1.1 conversion

Tags: c#, autofac

Good day.

I'm trying to convert one .NET 4.5 class library to .NETCoreApp 1.1 and stuck on one peace of code:

```
public virtual ILifetimeScope Scope()
{
    return AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope;
}
```

AutofacDependencyResolver was declared in Autofac.Integration.Mvc in .NET 4.5 but looks like it does not exist in .NETCoreApp 1.1.

So, how can I return the current ILifetimeScope now?

Thank you in advance, 
Serge

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core is a very, very different beast than classic ASP.NET on a full .NET Framework. It's much more like Web API (where there is no "central dependency resolver") than like MVC.

I'd recommend checking out [the ASP.NET Core integration documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html), especially the section on "Differences From ASP.NET Classic" which contains this bullet (among others):

> **No more DependencyResolver.** Other ASP.NET integration mechanisms
>   required setting up a custom Autofac-based dependency resolver in
>   various locations. With `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and
>   the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method, you now just return the
>   `IServiceProvider` and “magic happens.” Within controllers, classes,
>   etc. if you need to manually do service location, get an
>   `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept this as the answer.